# How to reset listview after searchview is closed in android?

Tags: android, listview, filter, baseadapter, searchview

I have implemented a listview with a baseadapter that is getting filtered (only matching items are shown) when the user searches for a query, but when there is no more text in the search bar and the search action is closed, I'm not able to reset (get back all the initial listview items) the listview with all the items. I'm posting my code below. Can someone help me how to reset the listview. I have tried to call the filter() in the OnCloseListener's onClose() method by passing empty string but it doesnt help.

**Activity class**

```
    public class MainPage extends ActionBarActivity {
    MainPageAdapter mainPageAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

        mainPageAdapter = new MainPageAdapter();
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.main_list);
        listView.setAdapter(mainPageAdapter);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StatePage.class);
                intent.putExtra("page number", i);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_page, menu);
//        return true;
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
//        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search State..");

        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                mainPageAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                mainPageAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                return true;
            }
        };
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textListener);

        SearchView.OnCloseListener closeListener = new SearchView.OnCloseListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                return false;
            }
        };
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(closeListener);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id)
        {
            case R.id.action_search:
                return true;
            case R.id.action_overflow:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class MainPageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    public ArrayList<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>();
    private QueryFilter queryFilter;
    ArrayList<String> temp;
    ArrayList<String> filterStateList;

    public MainPageAdapter()
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                alist.add("Apple");
                alist.add("Samsung");
                alist.add("HTC");
                //list goes on...
                temp = alist;
            }
        };
        thread1.start();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(alist != null){
            return alist.size();
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        if(alist != null){
            return alist.get(i);
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount(){
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if(view == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.state_list, viewGroup, false);
        }
        String state = alist.get(i);
        TextView stateTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.state_view);
        stateTextView.setText(state);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.flag_view);

        switch(i)
        {
            case 0:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);
                break;
            case 1:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.samsung);
                break;
            case 2:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.HTC);
                break;
            //list goes on...
            default:
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(queryFilter == null){
            queryFilter =  new QueryFilter();
        }
        return queryFilter;
    }

    private class QueryFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if(charSequence!= null && charSequence.length()> 0)
            {
                filterStateList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int i=0; i< temp.size(); i++)
                {
                    if((temp.get(i).toLowerCase().contains(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase())))
                    {
                        filterStateList.add(temp.get(i));
                    }
                }
                filterResults.count = filterStateList.size();
                filterResults.values = filterStateList;
            }
            else
            {
                filterResults.count = alist.size();
                filterResults.values = alist;
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            alist = (ArrayList<String>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apply following in your code and check if it works,

```
 final MenuItem searchMenuItem = optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.search);
final SearchView searchView =
        (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();

searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean queryTextFocused) {
        if(!queryTextFocused) {
            searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
            searchView.setQuery("", false);
        }
    }
});
```

or following may also work

```
       SearchView.OnCloseListener closeListener = new SearchView.OnCloseListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            mainPageAdapter.getFilter().filter("");
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Comment: I tried both of them but they're not working. The second solution with empty string doesn't match any items in the listview.

Comment: I have some logical error in my code and fixed it now. Your second solution worked for me even without using filter. Thank you

Comment: @prudhvi: it should have worked as you have specified `{filterResults.count = alist.size();filterResults.values = alist;}` in else part

Comment: @prudhvi: you can accept it as answer by clicking on accept button near my answer.so that it can be helpful to future reference for other developers

Comment: man! you are awsome.I would have given you a gift if you are here anywhere..great help.Thanks.@ Mehul Joisar

Comment: @RushiAyyappa: I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try many things like:

```
listView.setAdapter(null);
adapter.clear(); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() 
yourcollection.clear(); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//this removes all the views from your layout inside a tag like linearlayout
linearlayout.removeAllViews();
```

Use what suits you the most.

Comment: Hey, thank you for prompt reply. But I mean to ask how to get back all the initial listview items. I think you thought reset as in completely removing items from the listview.

Comment: you can try adapter.remove(itemsToremove) and later add using adapter.add() its simple man same can be donet to  the collection items